# 2FA problems with Thunderbird & Office365: allow cookies

Tags: office365, thunderbird, two-factor-authentication

After Microsoft's 2FA started asking to write numbers in the auth process a few days ago, the window that pops up in Thunderbird to connect to the Office365 account would immediately redirect to:

`https://authentification.[organization.org]/my.logout.php3?errorcode=19`

It turned out that it's because Thunderbird does not accept cookies from web pages (and that the auth window is a web page). So go to the Parameters > Private life > Web content section and either check the "Accept cookies" box, or add an exception for:

`login.microsoftonline.com`

Didn't find this solution on Internet so I'm posting it here in case it's useful for someone.

Using Thunderbird 102.11.0 (64 bits) on MacOS 13.3.1